# Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать и сохранить скриншот через visual studio

Tags: c#, экран

Вот и ввесь вопрос:) Скрин необходимо сделать на C#

Comment: И если можна то как сделать показ монитора:)

Comment: Вопросы должны быть более развёрнутые. Вы пробовали найти ответ в интернете? Что получилось, что нет?..

Answer (score 3):

*примерно* так:

```
Bitmap bit = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
Graphics graph = Graphics.FromImage(bit);

graph.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
graph.Dispose();

SaveFileDialog dialog = new SaveFileDialog();
if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
  bit.Save(dialog.FileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```